# How do I suppress Chrome from issuing "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" for my XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My XML HTTP request requests a URL that does not exist:

```
var url = 'http://redHerringObviouslyNonexistentDomainName.com';

var myHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myHttpRequest.open('GET', url, true);
myHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (myHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && myHttpRequest.status == 200) {
    // Do stuff with myHttpRequest.responseText;
  }
}
myHttpRequest.responseType = 'text';
myHttpRequest.send();
```

I'm OK with the URL not existing ... but I'm not OK with Chrome issuing the following error in the Console:

```
GET redHerringObviouslyNonexistentDomainName.com/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

How do I tell Chrome "I don't care that the URL does not exist - just suppress that error from the Console?"

If someone answers this question by buying that domain name, I will lol so hard ... but then you'll feel bad after I change the URL I use in this question.

Comment: why do you care what is output to the console?

Comment: It's just unprofessional to have error messages in the console. I'm writing an API.

Comment: requesting from a domain you know doesn't exist isn't exactly professional either

Answer (score 1):

as far as this problem, an option would be to send the request to a non-existent ip rather than a non-existent domain because it is throwing that error out of an attempt to find out what ip it points to failing. so by sending it to an ip that you know for a fact will not return anything you may be able to avoid this, although this is purely in theory and you could get an entirely different error thrown at you.
another option is to send the request and have the value returned made into a variable with

```
errorDomain = yourMethodOfRequestingStatus
```

this is pure theory and I have not tested any of the suggested methods but I hope it helped you at least a bit.